# Any reference book for the axiom of indifference or insufficient reason

Tags: bayesian, references

I need a book as a reference for the "principle of indifference" or "principle of insufficient reason". Any suggestion?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference) $\rightarrow$ ["Chapter IV. The Principle of Indifference"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YmCvAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA41&dq=%22principle+of+indifference%22&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22principle%20of%20indifference%22&f=false).